# Xamarin iOS app crash on startup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

After submitting an app to iTunes Connect, it got rejected, stating that the app crashes on launch. This behavior does not occur while running the app in the emulator. Also, the app works fine on Android, Google Play did not reject it whatsoever. So my main concerns are why is this happening ?

The app is a Xamarin Forms 2.0 ( latest version ) iOS application, ran with XCode 7.3 and built for iOS 9.3. In the crash log from Apple I saw they tested it on iOS 9.3.1.

Has anyone else gone through this? The log from Apple says that Thread 0 ( main thread ) has crashed.

Comment: I suggest you try on a device, it's often not the same behaviour as the simulator (for iOS, its simulator, and for android it's emulator).
Once you've tried that on a device, you'll most certainly have the crash. Then we can start helping. Without a stacktrace at least, we can't do much.
Also, if you dont' have any result in debug, try in release, and if not successful, try installing from an .ipa. If you don't get any crash from there you're gonna need to get creative.

Comment: Hello Zil, i'm trying to symbolize the crash log as we speak. It will take a bit of time however. Any possible reasons or suggestions ? I have 2 3 theories but it's gonna take a while to test them out. I believe the app is doing too much work on the main thread querying the language several times, thus resulting in an abort by watchdog. Not sure yet.

Comment: Could share the crash log? Apple usually provides the crash log in these scenarios to debug the issue

Comment: In a few hours when I get to my PC I will edit the question Prashant and include the crash log, hopefully symbolized.

Comment: Ok so after analyzing the crash log, I managed to reproduce the crash in the Simulator. It seems that the Linker is affecting a lot more features than I thought. With the Link All option, the crash reproduces in the Simulator. With Link SDK Assemblies it seems that the crash doesn't reproduce itself. We'll see after another review!

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced similar issue with ios app...
In my case app was crashing only on the 32 bit of the device.
The following are couple of changes done to resolve the issue:

1. Deployment target updated to 9.0.
2. Linker option updated to support all the iOS architectures (ARMv7 + ARMv7s + ARM64). Note:- Previously it was only targeted for (ARMv7 + ARM64) but this option will increase ipa size.
3. NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSCameraUsageDescription privacy settings were added to the info.plist file.
4. Latest stable release of xamarin version was updated (4.2).

Also make sure that the plugin initialization are done inside appdelegate.cs file not inside main.cs file

I hope this might help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have followed everything and it is still crashing!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my app after updating Xamarin Studio and after trying more than 20 different solutions and searching in all forums and stackoverflow it turns out that Visual Studio for mac has a bug and sometimes it adds more than one MtouchLink configuration in *iOS.csproj file :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' ">
...
<MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
<MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
```

In my case the IDE was saving two linker behaviors configurations and the app was crashing after showing the LaunchScreen image, only in release mode

To correct it I just edited the *iOS.csproj file with SublimeText and deleted the line :
`<MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>`

Hope it helps